# Delete the file if the filename with another extension is not present in the directory

Tags: linux, shell

Here I am writing a simple example.
I have files given below

```
FOO.sac
FOO.dsp
RFT.sac
NDT.sac
PST.sac
PST.dsp
```

I want to delete the files RFT.sac NDT.sac. Because these files have no extension files with the same name.

```
if [ -e file ] && [ -e file ]; then
echo "file exit"
else
rm file
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run a loop over files of extension of type `.sac` and see if the corresponding `.dsp` file is there and if not remove the file

```
for file in *.sac; do 
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    [ ! -e "${file%%.*}.dsp" ] && echo "$file"
done
```

The part `${file%%.*}` is a shell variable expansion which truncates everything after the last `.` and using it as `"${file%%.*}.dsp"` creates the filename with `.dsp` extesnion added.

Replace the `echo` with `rm` once you identify the files to be removed are matched as expected.

Comment: it removes  FOO.sac  PST.sac  also, I want to keep these file

Comment: *.dsp files already exits no need to create. the above code removes  FOO.sac  PST.sac  also, I want to keep these file since FOO.dsp PST.dsp exists

Comment: @rehman: I tested this and the files identified were only `NDT.sac` and `RFT.sac` to be deleted